# Cloud9 EC2 instance loses configuration when auto hibernating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I began putting together a project yesterday and decided that I'd like to use Cloud 9 as the development IDE. When I was setting up my dev environment, I selected that I wanted to create a new EC2 instance for the environment (t2.micro) and I put the cost-savings settings as 30 minutes (so that the environment will auto-hibernate after inactivity). I then proceeded to use Cloud 9 as I had in the past, which included some changes such as upgrading the version of Node.js and installing Django. Everything worked great until I went to bed. When I woke up and opened my environment again this morning, the instance was relaunched and none of the changes I made persisted, so I needed to do the updates/installations all over again.

Is there a way I can avoid this without having to turn off auto-hibernate (or is the root issue something else, and if so, how can I address it)? I don't particularly want to waste a bunch of compute time having my instance just sitting there idly, but it's really annoying having to spend a chunk of my morning re-configuring everything that I did yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the default Node version with `nvm`? If you manually set a Node version with the terminal but don't set it to default, the Node version will only apply to the one terminal session (it won't even persist to a new terminal tab).